# To add a new pod into an app with existing pod files

Tags: cocoapods

I have an app that that I made about 4 months ago which uses pods. This is the first app I ever used pods for. Now I am updating the app and have another pod I wish to implement in the app. I go into the pod file and add the line `pod 1234`. then in the terminal do I run a `pod install` or a `pod update`?

Read some doc on it but still not 100% clear as I am new to the concepts of pods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pod install` to install the new pod and keep the other pods at the previously installed version.

`pod update` to install the new pod and update the previously installed pods to their latest versions.

Full details [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/terminal/commands.html#group_installation).